# With Form Of A Beast, if you use Strength Of A Bear, what damage do your attacks do?

Tags: spells, modiphius-2d20

The 2D20 Conan spell Form Of A Beast says that you "gain a Natural attack of 4 dice", but in the various iterations of the spell (such as Strength Of A Bear and Body Of A Wolf), it says you "gain its attacks", which would appear to do *less* base damage than 4 dice (if you subtract the bonus the creature gains from its own Brawn).

For example, a Bear's Bite is listed at doing 6 dice of damage, but presumably this takes into account the Bear's listed Brawn of 12, which would add 3 of those dice, meaning the base damage of the Bite is actually 3...

So what would the actual damage be when assuming those forms and gaining their attacks (instead of just casting the base form of the spell and getting a natural attack of 4)?

Answer (score 1):

The basic spell description on p179-181 is a little contradictory to the sample transformations sidebar. The main description says your abilities are unaffected and you gain the 4die attack, and doesn't even mention the sidebar options at all.

The way I read it is the default is no stat changes, and you get a 4 die attack, modified by your normal Melee damage bonus. If you choose one of the specific forms in the sidebar, then those overrule the default, giving you stat bonuses as well as specific attacks.

Note that the specific forms also have higher difficulty and Resolve costs, and that momentum spends also let you get the stat bonuses. In theory, you could also stack the momentum spend onto one of the specific forms - if you cast Strength of a Bear with 5 successes, you could take a 6 die increase to your Brawn, as well as use the bite attack of the Bear, at a cost of 3 Resolve.